# Get location of Box folder in Mac

Tags: box-api

So I'm building an app that needs to know the location of the `Box` folder on the user's Mac - not just when it is in the default `/Users/{user}/Box Documents folder`, but anywhere if they may have shifted it.

Is this location stored in a file or some environment variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by no means an officially supported solution, but I managed to locate this in

```
{user}/Library/Application Support/Box Sync/LastLoggedInUserInfo.xml
```